# Results are different within & outside the "for" loop when using pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Dataset are from Kaggle Titanic competition.

My input:

```
data = [train_data, test_data]

for d in data:
    print('Initial: ', d.columns)
    d = pd.get_dummies(d, columns=['Sex', 'Embarked'], drop_first=True)
    print('Finished: ', d.columns)
    print('-'*10)
    
print('\nOut the loop: ', train_data.columns)
```

The output:

```
Initial: Index(['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked', 'Title'],
      dtype='object')
Finished: Index(['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch',
       'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Title', 'Sex_male', 'Embarked_Q', 'Embarked_S'],
      dtype='object')
----------
Initial: Index(['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch',
       'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked', 'Title'],
      dtype='object')
Finished: Index(['Pclass', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket',
       'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Title', 'Sex_male', 'Embarked_Q', 'Embarked_S'],
      dtype='object')
----------

Out the loop: Index(['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
       'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked', 'Title'],
      dtype='object')
```

Why do i have "'Sex_male', 'Embarked_Q', 'Embarked_S'" when print within the for loop, while don't have these features outside the for loop?

BTW, when i am creating a new feature (eg. d['Rela'] = d['SibSp'] + d['Parch']) rather than using get_dummies within the for loop, I can have the new feature ('Rela') outside the for loop.

Comment: `d = ` just creates a new dataframe... it doesn't affect `train_data`...

Comment: @JonClements But when i write `for d in data: d['Rela'] = d['SibSp'] + d['Parch']`, i could have "Rela" in train_data and test_data. Don't understand what's the differences between these two situation.